# Correct way to get state value from inside getServerSideProps getState() or useSelector()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga

So I have been trying to use `next-redux-wrapper` and make request to my api endpoint to fetch blogs with `redux-saga`. I'm able to fetch data to the state. My only doubt here is, what is the correct way to get a particular value from the state; I know the two solutions are using `store.getState()` inside `getServerSideProps()` or using `useSelector()` hook in the function component?

**As far as I understand**, using `useSelector()` would go against server-side rendering as it calls the data in the client side, i think. Is it correct?

My code using `useSelector()`:

```
export default function BlogsList(){
    const blogs = useSelector(state => state.blogReducer.blogReducer.blog);

    return(
        <div className="mainCon">
            <ul>
                {blogs.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.author}>
                        <span>{item.author}</span><br/>
                        <span>{item.title}</span>
                        <h4>{item.body_delta}</h4>
                        <p>{item.body_html}</p>
                        <p>{item.created_on}</p>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps( async ({store, req}) =>{
    store.dispatch({type: FETCH_BLOG_LIST});
    store.dispatch(END);
    await store.sagaTask.toPromise();
});
```

My code using `store.getState()`:

```
export default function BlogsList({blogs}){
    return(
        <div className="mainCon">
            <ul>
                {blogs.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.author}>
                        <span>{item.author}</span><br/>
                        <span>{item.title}</span>
                        <h4>{item.body_delta}</h4>
                        <p>{item.body_html}</p>
                        <p>{item.created_on}</p>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}


export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps( async ({store, req}) =>{
    store.dispatch({type: FETCH_BLOG_LIST});
    store.dispatch(END);
    await store.sagaTask.toPromise();

    const blog = store.getState();
    const blogs = blog.blogReducer.blog;
      
    return { props: {blogs}, };
});
```

Which approach properly follows server-side rendering logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code using `store.getState ():` is the correct approach and as you mentioned, useSelector is used to get state on the client side. With next-redux-wrapper two stores are created, one for the server(getStaticProps, getServerSideProps) and one for the client

Comment: So after hydration, if I need to access some data from the store then it's appropriate to use `useSelector()` on the client side?

Comment: Yeah and you'll still need to dispatch the same action

Comment: If this responds to your question, you can mark it as the accepted response